# Better Observable typescript pattern for if x of Observable<X> else y of Observable<Y>

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I have 2 observables and I want to get a value from X if it exists, else get it from Y. The following works for me, but I am looking for a more succinct pattern.

```
import {of} from 'rxjs';
import {map, mergeMap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {getX, getY} from './getXY';

// getX(id: string): Observable<X>; // gets an X asyncronously
// getY(id: string): Observable<Y>; // gets a Y asyncronously

let id = "abc";

// get an X, or a Y if not X, that matches the id
getX(id).pipe(mergeMap((x: X) => {
  if (x) {
    return of(x);
  } else {
    return getY(id).pipe(map((y: Y) => {
      if (y) {
        return y;
      }
    }));
  }
})).subscribe((xy: X | Y) => { ... }
```

It seems to me that the of(x) is going in the wrong direction - that perhaps instead of mergeMap, there is a way to conditionally extract the Y from the getY without the need for the of(x).

Ideally I will write a getXY that does all that and returns an Observable<X | Y> that can be subscribed to.

---

I create a [codepen](https://codepen.io/neonguru/pen/XBJPVo) with the original example and cartant's answer. Notice that when getX returns 'x', cartant's still calls getY - that is why I did not mark his answer as the solution. Feel free to fork and add your own solution.

Answer (score 4):

You could implement your `getXY` function like this:

```
function getXY(id: string /* or whatever */) {
  return concat(
    getX(id).pipe(filter(x => Boolean(x))),
    getY(id).pipe(filter(y => Boolean(y)))
  ).pipe(take(1));
}
```

The function's return type will be inferred to be `Observable<X | Y>` and the implementation is a little less imperative.

Using `concat` will ensure that the observable returned by `getY` will only be subscribed to if the observable returned by `getX` either completes without emitting or emits an falsy value.

Comment: Problem is: getY is always called so performance is less than the original.

Comment: Typically, calling a function that returns an observable is less expensive than subscribing to the returned observable, as observables are lazy and often perform slow, asynchronous tasks. In the unlikely situation that you have a getter with which your creating an observable is the bottleneck, you could wrap the `getY` with [`defer`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/defer). Or, even better, you could use `defer` in the implementation of `getY` so that it's even lazier.

Comment: `function getY(id) { return defer(() => /* whatever is your current implementation */); }`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution with operators, that doesn't call getY when getX succeeds is:

```
function getXY(id: string): Observable<X|Y> {
  return getX(id).pipe(mergeMap((x: X) => {
    if (x) {
      return of(x);
    } else {
      return getY(id);
    }
  }));
};
```

I have updated the [codepen](https://codepen.io/neonguru/pen/XBJPVo) with this getXY function included. As well as getXYcartant - and the following getXYnew:

`Observable.create` is another possible answer since it doesn't call getY if X is null:

```
function getXYnew(id: string): Observable<X|Y> { 
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    getX(id).subscribe(x => {
      if (x) {
        observer.next(x);
        observer.complete();
      } else {
        getY(id).subscribe(y => {
          observer.next(y);
          observer.complete();
        });
      }
    });
  });
};
```

But this, like the other more performance optimal options, creates another Observable.